Go - UDP server read buffer does not change anything
I have a simple UDP server which listens for packets, waits 50 millisecond to behave as if there is an operation going on, and then prints the message to the terminal. Here is the server code:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "log/slog"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    udpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "0.0.0.0:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", udpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    slog.Info("UDP server listening", "addr", udpAddr, "workers", numCpu)

    go startWorker(0, conn)

    // Block forever
    <-make(chan struct{})
}

func startWorker(id int, conn *net.UDPConn) {
    slog.Info("Starting worker", "id", id)

    i := 0
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        _, _, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
        if err != nil {
            slog.Error("failed to read UDP message", "err", err, "worker", id)
            continue
        }

        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)

        fmt.Print(i, " > ", string(buf))
        i += 1
    }
}

I have a go client code which simply just sends a string message to this server once. Here is the client code:
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    udpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "0.0.0.0:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, udpAddr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Send a message to the server
    _, err = conn.Write([]byte("Hello UDP Server\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}


I wanted to test how many packets can be handled in the server. So what I have done is, I ran the client code 10000 times sequentially to see how many of them are going to be handled. But everytime, only about 400-500 packets are processed. Here is how I did the test from the terminal:
time (for i in $(seq 10000); do ./client; done)

There were no error logs and the output was:
real    0m12,538s
user    0m10,667s
sys     0m4,014s

I assumed this could be a problem due to os buffer limitations. So I added the following code before go startWorker(id, conn) in the server code:
// 1 GB
if err = conn.SetReadBuffer(1024 * 1024 * 1024); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

After doing the exact same test, number of processed packets became 600-700. There is no way that 1 GB of buffer is not enough for 10000 of this simple "Hello UDP Server\n" message. Can anyone explain to me the reason behind this behavior and how can I fix it?
P.S.: I am using Ubuntu 22.04

0.0.0.0 is a valid listen-address, but not a valid target address. You need to provide an actual IP address of the server for the client to send to.

@user207421 Are you sure about that? If that was the case I assume there would be an error thrown when dialing the address. Even if no errors for some reason unknown to me, there should be no packets arriving to my server, but I actually see them arriving in the logs of the server. Maybe golang net library handles the resolving of 0.0.0.0 under the hood?

Just FYI - your code (did need the increased read buffer) received all messages successfully on my laptop (Win11).

Your code works for me. Try to increase the size of the UDP buffer of your operating system.

@IvanSharapenkov yup. There actually seems to be a max buffer size of 450000ish bytes in my OS. I increased it and now everything works fine. Write an answer and I will accept.

@AhmetYazıcı Nice to hear that. I have posted an answer.
